# How to loop through columns in R to create plots?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have three columns in a dataframe: age, gender and income.

I want to loop through these columns and create plots based on the data in them.

I know in stata you can loop through variables and then run commands with those variables. However the code below does not seem to work, is there an equivalent way to do what I want to do in R?

```
groups <- c(df$age, df$gender, df$income) 
for (i in groups){   
df %>% group_by(i) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = i)) +
    geom_col()  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use the tidyverse. Loop through a vector of grouping variable names with `map`. On every iteration, you can evaluate `!!sym(variable)` the variable name to `group_by`. Alternatively, we can use `across(all_of())`, wihch can take strings directly as column names. The rest of the code is pretty much the same you used.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

groups <- c('age', 'gender', 'income') 

## with    !!(sym(.x))

map(groups, ~ 
    df %>% group_by(!!sym(.x)) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = i)) +
    geom_col()
   )

## with    across(all_of())

map(groups, ~ 
    df %>% group_by(across(all_of(.x))) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = i)) +
    geom_col()
   )
```

If you want to use a for loop:

```
groups <- c('age', 'gender', 'income')

for (i in groups){   
df %>% group_by(!!sym(i)) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = i)) +
    geom_col()  
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is also great. Could you explain what !!sim does? Also how does the tilda evaluate things?

Comment: The tilde is the short form for lambda/anonymous functions in purrr and other tydiverse packages like dplyr. It makes writing lambda functions a bit easier. `function(x) x` can then be simplyfied into `~ .x`. In the above answer, the tilde could be replaced with `function (.x)`

Comment: The double bang sin `!!` is from the rlang package (and used in dplyr too).  The "groups" variable is a string. when you convert it to symbol with sym() it will then becames a symbol (a name-object correspondence key,). Then the double bang sign (`!!`) evaluates the symbol, which gets us the desired column. If you use the column name directly as a string it wont work because it is not yet associated to any object in the dataframe. group_by() does not accept column names directly. You have to convert to symbol and evaluate.

Comment: This can be done with other dplyr functions too, like select() and mutate() or across(), with !!(sym(x)) or with specific helper functions that take strings directly as column names, such as `all_of()` or `if_all`

Comment: I included a version of the answer with `across(all_of))` . It is clearer for begginers than `!!(sym(.x))` and is pretty much the same for this.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the !!sym(.x) for a file name? Something like this?
      ggsave("results/JS05 - Survey/",!!sym(.x),".png")

Comment: Or do we actually want the string representation now?

Comment: In that case you are looking for the actual value of the object .x as a string, so you don't have to convert to symbol, just use `ggsave( paste0("results/JS05 - Survey/", .x, ".png")

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply`

```
df <- data.frame(age = sample(c("26-30", "31-35", "36-40", "41-45"), 20, replace = T),
                 gender = sample(c("M", "F"), 20, replace = T),
                 income = sample(c("High", "Medium", "Low"), 20, replace = T),
                 prop   = runif(20))

lapply(df[,c(1:3)], function(x) ggplot(data = df, aes(y = df$prop, x = x))+ geom_col())
```

Comment: Thanks so much, if I don't know the column numbers, can I reference them by name in the lapply?

Comment: @entropy Yes you can.